# Microsoft SQL Server: trigger to check that the sum of a field grouped by another field does not exceed a particular value?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table where a person can log a number of hours on a day:

```
|__person__|__day__|__hours__|
|   1      |  1    |   4     |
|___2______|__1____|___2_____|
...
```

I want to create a trigger that doesn't allow the sum of hours to be greater than a specific value, for example 24, **for a single person on a specific day**.

Multiple rows can be inserted on multiple days simultaneously, and the trigger should then check that each day still has a valid number of hours for each person.

I have tried reading the documentation and similar questions here, but haven't been able to solve this, and have very little experience with SQL Server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: triggers are probably a last choice in most situations because they can be slow (if not written properly) and they can make your system harder to maintain and debug and less scalable: http://devproconnections.com/sql-server/reasons-avoid-triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a user defined function for this and create a contratins using that user defined functions something like this...

### User-Defined Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_TotalHoursRemaining  (
                                                @PersonID INT 
                                              , @Day      INT
                                              )
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Hours INT 

SELECT @Hours = ISNULL(SUM([HOURS]), 0)
FROM Test_Table
WHERE Person = @PersonID
AND   [DAY] = @Day
GROUP BY Person , [DAY] 

  SET @Hours = 24 - @Hours;
 RETURN @Hours;
END
```

### Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Test_Table
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_hours_remaining 
       CHECK (((dbo.get_TotalHoursRemaining(Person , [Day])) >= 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a check constraint on that column, you are able to prevent any value greater than 24 to be inserted. Basically what that does is: when you run an insert statement and the hour sum turns out bigger than 24, you violate the constraint and it kills the transaction immediately.

Check this link to get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it would not check for the sum of hours in the table as you have stated it will only check for the hours in the row that is being inserted. you can have multiple rows with hours 23 for the same person and same day which is wrong. See my answer how you would handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for constraint,trigger is a overkill in this case.

This is based on assuming ,hours will be logged only once  per day against each id

```
create table dbo.test
(
    id int,
    hrs int
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_hrs CHECK (hrs <= 24);
```

You also can add constraint to restict least hours:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_hrs CHECK (hrs > 0 AND hrs <= 24);

insert into dbo.test
   select 1,25
```

You also can have a trigger if each per logs hours mutiple times a day and you want the sum to be < 24

```
create table dbo.test
(
    id int,
    hrs int,
    dayy datetime
);

create trigger trg_test
on dbo.test
after insert 
as
begin
    if exists(select id, sum(hrs) 
              from inserted i
              join test t on i.id = t.id
              group by id, dayy
              having sum(hrs) > 24)
       ---sum of hours per day exceeded...some thig like that--you can even insert to  log table '
insert into logtable
    select id, sum(hrs) 
    from inserted i
    join test t on i.id = t.id
    group by id, dayy
    having sum(hrs) > 24
end
rollback

end
```

Comment: this check constraint will allow more than 1 row with hours totalling more than 24.